# Unity says that 'Button' is not a Component and doesn't derive from Monobehavior

Tags: unity-game-engine

This was originally coded in unity 2018 then ported to unity 2019 because my main project is on that version. It works perfectly in unity 2018 (aside from that `button.clicked +=`  used to be `button.AddListener()`)

**The only relevant bit of the code is lines 12 - 17 but who knows.**

Script is attached to object with the Button component.

Unity 2019.4.11f1

Returns the following error with the setup listed above:

> ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'Button' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class ButtonProperties : MonoBehaviour {

    public ButtonType buttonType;
    public string dest;
    Button button;

    void Start()
    {

        button = GetComponent<Button>();
        //perform different functions dependant on the button type
        if (buttonType == ButtonType.Scene)
        {
            //add ButtonLoadScene as a listener to the the button
            button.clicked += ButtonLoadScene;
        }
        else if (buttonType == ButtonType.Menu)
        {
            button.clicked += ButtonLoadMenu;
        }


        //change button text to "Load Scene" + the name of the scene
        string str = "Load " + dest;
        GetComponentInChildren<TextElement>().text = str;
    }

    //private scene loader because event listeners cant take arguments >:(
    void ButtonLoadScene()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(dest);
    }

    void ButtonLoadMenu()
    {
        //array of all canvases in the scene
        Canvas[] canvases = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Canvas>();

        //foreach canvas
        foreach (Canvas canvas in canvases)
        {
            //if the canvases name is the desired name
            if (canvas.name == dest)
            {
                //turn all canvases off
                foreach (Canvas c in canvases)
                {
                    c.enabled = false;
                }

                //turn current canvas on
                canvas.enabled = true;

                //break loop
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public enum ButtonType
{
    Scene,
    Menu
};
```

I also tested this by adding a NewBehaviourScript to the button with `Button button;` and, in the start function, `Start() {button = GetComponent<Button>();`}
Same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using the wrong namespace for your button. Try changing:

```
using UnityEngine.UIElements;
```

to

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

There is a Button in both namespaces, but the one in UnityEngine.UI is likely the component you're working with.

Comment: it says that "UI" is not a namespace

Comment: Well that's strange. Can you post your namespaces again? https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.html

Comment: Is this script in it's own custom assembly definition?

Comment: Tried reimporting all, adding all default libraries, not only is UI not a namespace according to my computer, even though I know its supposed to exist, but the problem is still happening. It is not in its own assembly, at least I wouldn't think so

Answer (score 0):

Had somebody else on the team test the build, as I started to think from the comment thread, I was missing the UI library. Changing it to the UI library was the solution but not for me until I restarted the computer. Thank you Thomas Finch for the help.